# different result in binary and source of octomap_server

Tags: optimization, octomap, catkin, octomap-mapping, octomap-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

i have a problem, may be someone knows about it, when i install binary octomap_server and run it the result map is excellent but when i use from source and compile it in catkin the result is not continuously, many shots are lost! also the problem is not from tf. I’ve attached the pictures of two situation, the first one is generate by compiled octomap_server and second one is by binary octomap_server. also i downloaded the source from [here](https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap_mapping). also the parameters for both of them are same.
mu ubuntu is 12.04 and my ros is hydro.

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/105696/different-result-in-binary-and-source-of-octomap_server/) by [VahidD](https://answers.ros.org/users/4674/vahidd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2013-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks to me like the source version is dropping frames since it cannot keep up with the update speed. The problem is that the source checkout and compilation in catkin is by default done without any optimizations, as described in [this related question](http://answers.ros.org/question/71965/catkin-compiled-code-runs-3x-slower/).

If you instead run `catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` it should work better.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VahidD](https://answers.ros.org/users/4674/vahidd/) on 2013-11-29**:
thank you so much.